# Joining column spread across multiple rows based on condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table for employee with comment spread across multiple rows. Those need to be joined into a single row. To identify which rows can be joined, we need to use date field - if date is present and there is subsequent row with no date then that denote start of comment for employee. If however there is single row with no date with no prior date row as well then that is considered as new comment. The order in which comment are entered (identity column) is also provided so LEAD function was the way I was trying
Below Table is what we have:
[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGysW.png)

| EmployeeId | Date | Comment | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2021-01-08 | This is only first part | 1 |
| 1001 | NULL | this is the second | 2 |
| 1001 | NULL | and this is third part | 3 |
| 1001 | 2021-01-15 | This is a new comment for same | 4 |
| 1002 | 2021-01-16 | This one has subsequent comment | 5 |
| 1002 | 2021-01-16 | The second comment | 6 |
| 1003 | NULL | This is single comment | 7 |
| 1003 | 2021-01-12 | This is also single comment | 8 |

The result we expect is :
[Result Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSPyF.png)

| EmployeeId | Date | Comment | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2021-01-08 | This is only first part this is the second and this is third part | 1 |
| 1001 | NULL | This is a new comment for same | 4 |
| 1002 | 2021-01-15 | This one has subsequent comment The second comment | 5 |
| 1003 | 2021-01-16 | This is single comment | 7 |
| 1003 | 2021-01-16 | This is also single comment | 8 |

I am trying the lead function but not able to get how to join n number of row based on condition. Any help?

SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE Comments(
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] null,
    [Comment] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Order] [int] NULL
    )
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1001','1/8/2021', 'This is only first part', 1)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1001',NULL, 'this is the second', 2)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1001',NULL, 'and this is third part', 3)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1001','1/15/2021', 'This is a new comment for same', 4)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1002','1/16/2021', 'This one has subsequent comment', 5)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1002','1/16/2021', 'The second comment', 6)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1003',NULL, 'This is single comment', 7)
INSERT INTO Comments VALUES('1003','1/12/2021', 'This is also single comment', 8)
```

Comment: You say rows need to be joined but I think you mean the rows need to be merged.  JOIN has a specific meaning in SQL and that makes your question very un-clear.

Comment: Why does the expected results have a null for the 2nd row's Date.  I'd expect it to be 2021-01-15 since that is what it was in the row with that comment.

Comment: Why is the date for the 4th row 2012-1-16?  It is null in the source table

Comment: Why is the date for the last row 2021-01-16, it is 2021-01-12 in the source table.

Comment: 1. You are right - I need them merged. I used joined not in SQL sense. 2. Yes, you are right - it my bad in typing. 3. Yes, you are right .it should be null. 4. You are right again... I think you understood it way better!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left a bunch of comments about details in your "expected results" that did not make sense given your requirements.  If I go by your stated requirements then here is a solution:

First normalize the table to have dates so we can use group by

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
       COALESCE([Date],
                LAG([Date] OVER (ORDER BY [Order] ASC), -- Get the prior one if null
                MIN([Date] OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY [Date] ASC)) AS [Date],  -- Get the smallest one if the last two are null
       Comment,
       [Order]
FROM sometableyoudidnotname
```

Now that we have this table we can use group by and string_agg

```
SELECT EmployeeID,
       MIN(cDate) as [DATE],
       STRING_AGG(Comment, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [ORDER] ASC) AS Comment
FROM (
  SELECT EmployeeID, 
         COALESCE([Date],
                  LAG([Date] OVER (ORDER BY [Order] ASC), -- Get the prior one if null
                  MIN([Date] OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY [Date] ASC)) AS [Date],  -- Get the smallest one if the last two are null
         Comment,
         [Order]
  FROM sometableyoudidnotname) X
GROUP BY EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thanks @Hogan.. This worked just like I wanted. I did change the group by to date since I needed date wise - but the logic is perfect!! Thanks!!!